# Why is my SHA-1 hash not 28 or 40 characters?

Tags: c#, password-encryption

I'm using SqlMembershipProvider in an aspnet project for user and password management. For (reasons) I am trying to duplicate the salt-and-hash method that the system uses. A search revealed a short algorithm that appends the salt to the password and then uses

```
HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(passPlusSalt);
return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
```

to generate an encrypted string. This matches what the system spits out, and is 28 characters because it's base-64 encoded: 160 bits / 6 bits = 26.66, and Base64 encoding rounds that up to 28, the next multiple of 4. Sure, ok.

BUT: there are working accounts in the system that have 44-character encrypted passwords, and some that are 64 characters. I'd assume these might be hexadecimal, but they're not - they use the same alphabet (ie A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, trailing =, though my sample size is small and I haven't seen a /). And now I presume they're just different encoding methods, but I am reluctant to ship a change that I can't guarantee works.

Why and/or how do you blow up a 160-bit hash to 44 bytes, or 64 bytes? How does that work in a system that will also store 28-byte strings?

If an encryption system is storing 28, 44, and 64 byte hashes, doesn't that imply that it is (randomly?) using different hashing algorithms? If it's not random, upon what is SqlMembershipProvider deciding which hash to use?

Comment: "Why and/or how do you blow up a 160-bit hash to 44 bytes, or 64 bytes?" You don't. That's not the hashing algorithm that is being used. Your initial assumption is incorrect. Simple as that. 44 bytes corresponds to SHA256 for example.

Comment: Ah, they do not use SHA-1? NOONE should use that anymore - it was declared unsafe AGES ago. Like beginning 2011. Can it be some of the codes are in hashed by OTHER than SHA-1? Anyone insisting on SHA-1 these days is doing something that legally is gross neglect.

Comment: Don't use SHA-1, or SHA-2, or any of those hashing methods, for password hashing. They're very fast, and therefore very easy to brute force.

Comment: Very easy to brute force, LOL. I mean, sure, if you have millions of dollars and 100 years to break single SHA1 hash. SHA1 is less safe than say SHA2 or SHA3, sure, but it doesn't mean it is unsafe. No reasonable preimage attack exists for SHA1 for example.

Comment: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha384.html